# Concourse docker container not starting

Tags: docker, docker-compose, concourse

I'm running into an issue after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. Concourse is the only docker stuff i've got running on that machine. I do have the feeling that something with the networking is broken somehow, as I'm also getting a 502 when trying to access concourse over the web and my nginx is telling me `recv() failed (104: Unknown error) while reading response header from upstream`. I've searched the internet already and came up with almost nothing matching the described error. Any idea what could be the problem?

Log from the web container:

```
web_1     | {"timestamp":"2023-04-10T11:30:48.118827840Z","level":"info","source":"atc","message":"atc.cmd.start","data":{"session":"1"}}
web_1     | {"timestamp":"2023-04-10T11:32:58.344826534Z","level":"error","source":"atc","message":"atc.db.failed-to-open-db-retrying","data":{"error":"dial tcp 172.18.0.2:5432: connect: connection timed out","session":"3"}}
```